# How to avoid Google Apps to mark emails as "Pending" on important e-mails

Tags: google-workspace, gmail

We use Google Apps to handle our company mail, and we are experiencing that lots of emails get caught in the "Manage pending messages".

That means we currently go through this every few days, and allow 2-3 emails to go through. We never experience actual spam, but always important e-mails here.

How to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Go into the Settings and under Moderation in the Spam Messages section click the drop menu and select Skip the moderation and post to the group."

[source](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/63137/emails-pushed-into-pending-in-google-apps-groups)